# Can mage hand block magic missile?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154357/can-the-mage-hand-cantrip-block-or-catch-a-thrown-object) asks if the spell [mage hand](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mage-hand) can catch thrown objects. But if you managed to place the mage hand in the way of a spell, such as [fire bolt](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fire-bolt) or [magic missile](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-missile), would the spell be blocked by the mage hand?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Magic Missile: no

This is the simple one; magic missile has no attack roll or saving throw, so *nothing* can stop it short of something that specifically calls out that it is capable of doing so (such as the Shield spell, for example).

Note how it just says:

> Each dart hits a creature of your choice that you can see within range.

## Firebolt: not really, but flavor, sure

Mage Hand does not specifically have any interaction with any attack spells, but there is a simple option available to everyone that lets you "block" Firebolt, which would be taking the Dodge action.

If you tell me "I'm taking the Dodge action and I'm going to try and block any incoming attacks with my Mage Hand" then sure, I'd let you do that. Of course, you could also take that action with an active Mage Hand and the result would be the same, but it's cooler this way.

## Mechanics

The basic reason why the question has no real answer other than the above is that you ask "If you place it in the way of the spell", but the Mage Hand does not give any of its own mechanics for doing that, so mechanically you can't do it. At best, you can use some other mechanic to do roughly the same.

Note that if you want a giant hand that blocks attacks and enemies coming for you, you want Bigby's Hand, but that's a 5th level spell, not a cantrip, and it gives you an idea of how powerful something like that is.

Comment: Another good spell to contrast would be Bigby's Hand, which is a hand-shaped spell that *can* provide partial cover against attacks.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson isn't that what I say in the last paragraph? :P

Comment: @Erik *Bigby’s hand* granted that paragraph partial cover and Ryan missed it.

Comment: @Erik Sorry, I was reading on mobile and I guess I scrolled too far on my tiny phone screen.

Comment: It is kind of strange that nothing can stop a magic missile within range though even if line of effect is unavailable. For example, you could cast magic missile at an enemy wizard at the end of a corridor and it will hit even if the wizard cast invisibilty on a gelataneous cube which is between you and the wizard and entirly filling the corridor.

Answer (score 1):

#### Blocking *magic missile* is a function of the spell *shield*.

*Shield* says:

> An invisible barrier of magical force appears and protects you. Until the start of your next turn, you have a +5 bonus to AC, including against the triggering attack, and *you take no damage from magic missile.*

There is a spell that can block *magic missile*, and it costs a 1st level spell slot and your reaction.

#### In general, since *mage hand* doesn't say it can block spells, it cannot block spells.

5th Edition has a "specific beats general" rule, which states:

> If a specific rule contradicts a general rule, the specific rule wins.

Since *magic missile* states:

> Each dart hits a creature of your choice,

each dart just hits the creature. To block *magic missile* a feature has to explicitly call out *magic missile*, as we see in the spell description of *shield*.

This applies in general as well, since *mage hand* doesn't say it can block spells as you describe, it cannot block spells as you describe - the spell description is the effect of the spell:

> Each spell description in Chapter 11 begins with a block of information, including the spell's name, level, school of magic, casting time, range, components, and duration. *The rest of a spell entry describes the spell's effect.*

Since the spell description of *mage hand* does not include blocking spells, blocking spells is not an effect of *mage hand*.