# Does standing behind another PC provide cover?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranged-attack, cover

I came across this in my campaign, where a player used *Investiture of Wind* because there was a mini horde of skeletons on higher ground about to shoot another volley of arrows. One of the other players (Medium-sized), used their movement to stand behind the first player (also Medium-sized).

The spells says: *"Ranged weapon attacks made against you have disadvantage on the attack roll."* (XGE, p.160)

The player suggested that any arrows targeting him would also have disadvantage. I disagreed with this, but it did make me think whether standing directly behind the other PC would provide cover.

I gave him 1/2 cover in the end (so a +2 to AC), but I'm not sure now. (PHB, p.196)

### Can you use another PC as a "obstacle" to create cover? If so, how much? Does size matter?

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Thank you @Someone_Evil - I think it provides a half-answer to be honest because it mentions providing 1/2 cover which is encouraging as I ruled that - but it still leaves me thinking whether it wouldn't be 3/4 (as they were both Medium sized). I'll amend that to make it more specific to what happened in game.

Comment: I do believe the size restrictions, if they exist, are covered by the duplicate.  It asks "Do size or status effects affect anything?" So answers would address this if there were any additional rules regarding creature size and cover. Related to that is [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165184)

Comment: Thank you @Medix2 - I think I can piece a good answer from the two links: 
https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50731/do-other-creatures-provide-cover
and https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165184/shooting-through-spaces-occupied-by-a-large-creature